# I cannot get the localhost webserver on firefox to display jpg or jpeg files

Tags: firefox, localhost

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Firefox. I cannot display jpg files when browser starts up. But if I click on ICON there is no problem. I am attaching a few screen shots. Am adding display from "env".

```
/usr/lib/icons/tm$ identify query.jpg

query.jpg JPEG 236x42 236x42+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 2.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000


env
SSH_AGENT_PID=1894
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-12oggk/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=23cbfe42352526df1a184da90000000a-1367744391.998295-447140937
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
WINDOWID=60818196
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-12oggk
USER=syedk
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_10
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd
=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=0
1;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.
tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz
=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.d
eb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31
:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=0
1;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.x
bm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;
35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mk
v=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;3
5:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=0
=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*
.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00
;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga
=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-12oggk/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/syedk-ThinkPad-T410:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1859,unix/syedk-ThinkP
ad-T410:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1859
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/syedk/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin:/home/syed
k/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_10/bin
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
PWD=/usr/lib/icons/tm
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_10
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1848
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/syedk
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=syedk
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-U7ZeU2sFyQ,guid=b42a287c3f51591
210fff2d700000019
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DISPLAY=:0.0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/syedk/.Xauthority
OLDPWD=/usr/lib/icons
_=/usr/bin/env
```